# How to securely XOR two passphrases in JavaScript?

Tags: passwords, xor, password-hashing

Is following approach secure?

Planning on using implementation to XOR two passphrases before feeding result to Argon2.

```
const xor = (a: string, b: string) => {
  if (a.length > b.length) {
    b = `${b}${b.substring(0, a.length - b.length)}`
  } else if (b.length > a.length) {
    a = `${a}${a.substring(0, b.length - a.length)}`
  }
  let result = ""
  for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    result += (
      parseInt(a.charAt(index), 16) ^ parseInt(b.charAt(index), 16)
    ).toString(16)
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, XOR is almost never the answer in these kind of circumstances.

With XOR it might well be that certain values of the passwords `a` and `b` would cancel each other our, for instance. If I were an attacker the very first that I would do is to try all zero strings up to a certain size, as that would indicate identical passwords. That is however only the most obvious problem that might be encountered.

---

Actually, just concatenation of the passwords and some indication of password size or a unique value as separator of at least one of them would be a better idea. The size is required to provide slightly more security, as otherwise some the passwords may overflow into each other, e.g. `somethingcompletely` and `different` would create the same string as `something` and `completelydifferent`. However, simply including a special character would overcome this issue: `somethingcompletelydifferent` and `somethingcompletelydifferent` are indeed different strings. You could use a non-printable character such as the [ASCII Unit Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) instead of the Unicode owl of course, but make sure that it isn't dropped somewhere in the process.

Here is the initial calculation in Argon2, after which the password isn't used anymore. As you can see, it directly hashes most of the input data including the password. For some other PBKDF's such as PBKDF2 it might make sense to perform an initial hash, but for Argon2 this initial hash is already included in the algorithm.

> ```
> buffer ← parallelism ∥ tagLength ∥ memorySizeKB ∥ iterations ∥ version ∥ hashType
>     ∥ Length(password)       ∥ Password
>     ∥ Length(salt)           ∥ salt
>     ∥ Length(key)            ∥ key
>     ∥ Length(associatedData) ∥ associatedData
>  H0 ← Blake2b(buffer, 64) //default hash size of Blake2b is 64-bytes
> ```

(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2))

Because of this initial hash there is no real limit to the password size in Argon2 (passwords of 4GiB or more are not often used).

---

Note that this answer directly targets the XOR construction. It might well be that different strategies exist that would be even better than the one proposed here for a particular purpose (e.g. using Argon2 on two passwords separately and using HKDF on the concatenated result).

Comment: Thanks for helping out! One aspect I like about XOR is it is order agnostic… that said, if I understood your answer correctly, concatenation is more secure.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to establish a governance scheme whereby two independent parties each have a passphrase. Without both, decryption cannot occur. I am aware of Shamir Secret Sharing, but given I am trying to achieve a 2 of 2, it is overkill.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: you could lexicographically order the passwords first.

Comment: It is naive to consider each passphrase as additional entropy in the context of concatenation which means order does not affect security?

Comment: Love how concatenation allows for as many passphrases as one needs to establish complex governance schemes.

Comment: @sunknudsen Possibly, but it depends a lot on the use case. Maybe the passwords are related in some kind of way. Would be worse in case of XOR though, as you can then rule out specific combinations. A PBKDF is a strengthened PRF, so it should not be possible to get any information out of that. If you lexicographically order then the adversary only has to test in lexicographical order, but that cannot be avoided and it doesn't downgrade security significantly.

Comment: @sunknudsen: The math name for the property `foo(a,b) == foo(b,a)` is "commutativity", i.e. that they're commutative.  And yes, that's the property you need if both passwords should be required but their order doesn't matter.  Binary addition also has this property, but without the cancelling problem of add-without-carry (XOR).  Two identical inputs result in that output shifted 1 bit to the left.  (Treating ASCII or UTF-8 bytes as a BigInt in JavaScript would be inconvenient, but probably no more so than for XOR.)  However, for feeding a hash, it has no advantage over concatenation.

Comment: Addition will still remove information. If you have three passwords you can give 2 of them as static input and then iterate over all of the values of the third one to find the combination. I'd still prefer concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Maarten Bodewes answer.

I will refer to another aspect of the question. Just how to securely xor in Javascript, which is the title of the question, not why or if it really needed.

Personally I would prefer WebAssembly for any cryptographic related stuff since Javascript is a high level language. As you can understand since WASM is an intermediate low level language there is no contract that the outputed assembly will be the same on any browser, or from time to time, it is just more probably to be secure that plain Javascript. Lastly, another aspect of the security of web applications is that there are just so many other attack vectors that nobody will focus on your cryptography.

This is an example of C++ code with the corresponding WASM and the actual x86_64 that will be executed by the browser.

C++

```
int a(char **str1, int str1_size, char **str2, int str2_size, char**result) {
  
  if (str1_size != str2_size) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < str1_size; i++) {
    (*result)[i] = (*str1)[i] ^ (*str2)[i];
  }
}
```

WASM

```
(module
 (table 0 anyfunc)
 (memory $0 1)
 (export "memory" (memory $0))
 (export "_Z1aPPciS0_iS0_" (func $_Z1aPPciS0_iS0_))
 (func $_Z1aPPciS0_iS0_ (; 0 ;) (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32) (param $2 i32) (param $3 i32) (param $4 i32) (result i32)
  (block $label$0
   (br_if $label$0
    (i32.ne
     (get_local $1)
     (get_local $3)
    )
   )
   (set_local $1
    (i32.const 0)
   )
   (loop $label$1
    (i32.store8
     (i32.add
      (i32.load
       (get_local $4)
      )
      (get_local $1)
     )
     (i32.xor
      (i32.load8_u
       (i32.add
        (i32.load
         (get_local $2)
        )
        (get_local $1)
       )
      )
      (i32.load8_u
       (i32.add
        (i32.load
         (get_local $0)
        )
        (get_local $1)
       )
      )
     )
    )
    (set_local $1
     (i32.add
      (get_local $1)
      (i32.const 1)
     )
    )
    (br $label$1)
   )
  )
  (i32.const -1)
 )
)
```

x86_64

```
wasm-function[0]:
  sub rsp, 8                            ; 0x000000 48 83 ec 08
  cmp esi, ecx                          ; 0x000004 3b f1
  jne 0x35                              ; 0x000006 0f 85 29 00 00 00
 0x00000c:                              
  xor eax, eax                          ; 0x00000c 33 c0
 0x00000e:                              ; 0x00000e from: [0x000033]
  mov ecx, dword ptr [r15 + r8]         ; 0x00000e 43 8b 0c 07
  add ecx, eax                          ; 0x000012 03 c8
  mov ebx, dword ptr [r15 + rdx]        ; 0x000014 41 8b 1c 17
  add ebx, eax                          ; 0x000018 03 d8
  movzx ebx, byte ptr [r15 + rbx]       ; 0x00001a 41 0f b6 1c 1f
  mov ebp, dword ptr [r15 + rdi]        ; 0x00001f 41 8b 2c 3f
  add ebp, eax                          ; 0x000023 03 e8
  movzx ebp, byte ptr [r15 + rbp]       ; 0x000025 41 0f b6 2c 2f
  xor ebx, ebp                          ; 0x00002a 33 dd
  mov byte ptr [r15 + rcx], bl          ; 0x00002c 41 88 1c 0f
  add eax, 1                            ; 0x000030 83 c0 01
  jmp 0xe                               ; 0x000033 eb d9
 0x000035:                              
  mov eax, 0xffffffff                   ; 0x000035 b8 ff ff ff ff
  nop                                   ; 0x00003a 66 90
  add rsp, 8                            ; 0x00003c 48 83 c4 08
  ret                                   ; 0x000040 c3
```

The final assembly seems fine to me.

Lastly, probably a XOR operation because of it's simplicity, could work fine even in plain Javascript, I'm just posting this answer as an idea to alternative (more secure in general?) ways to implement cryptography in a browser.

EDIT: [Tool](https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/) used for the generated code.

Comment: That's hilariously inefficient asm, redoing the `(*result)` and other dereference every time through the loop.  Your function doesn't update the caller's pointers, only the pointed-to `char` data, so you could change the signature to `char *str1` and so on, and remove the extra level of indirection.  Then it JITs to fairly same asm with 3 pointer increments, but only one load and one store.

Comment: Oh, also you need `return 0;` at the end, otherwise you fall off a non-void function.  Firefox strangely assumes the loop must be infinite so that path of execution isn't reached, because that's UB in C++.  That's why you have a `jmp 0xe` instead of an `add esi, -1` / `test esi,esi` / `jnz 0x26`.  (Yes, Firefox is that dumb, according to https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/, not using FLAGS set by `add esi, -1`.)  Unfortunately we don't get SIMD (or even scalar 8 bytes at a time), like LLVM does when compiling straight to x86-64 asm with `-O3`.  Although not a big deal for short strings.

Comment: BTW, the "create a persistent link" button isn't working, or I don't know how to use it.  https://godbolt.org/z/5M6KMYqaY is the source I was looking at, with `clang -O3 -fno-vectorize -fno-unroll-loops` x86-64 asm (using the x86-64 SysV calling convention instead of whatever we get with WASM), as well as `clang -target wasm32`.

Comment: Please don't XOR strings in C and hope for a string output. If a given character happens to be the same in both input strings, the XOR will give zero, which will terminate the output string. So the XOR of "Aardvark" and "Antelope" is the null string. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: @abligh: This is XORing two explicit-length arrays that happen to hold `char` elements, not implicit-length *C strings*.  (e.g. like C++ `std:::string`, or perhaps how JavaScript engines hold strings.)  But good point, porting this to *just* take `char*` inputs without lengths would be fatally flawed.